# How does this obfuscated JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

How does the following JavaScript work?

I understand that it is minified code. I have tried de-obfuscating it a little, but I can't get a clear concept of how it achieves this effect.  I can see that it is using Strings for iteration of some kind, use of the Date object, strange string manipulation, Math functions, then the code prints itself.

How could the same effect be rewritten with a minimal example?

```
eval(z='p="<"+"pre>"/* ,.oq#+     ,._, */;for(y in n="zw24l6k\
4e3t4jnt4qj24xh2 x/* =<,m#F^    A W###q. */42kty24wrt413n243n\
9h243pdxt41csb yz/* #K       q##H######Am */43iyb6k43pk7243nm\
r24".split(4)){/* dP      cpq#q##########b, */for(a in t=pars\
eInt(n[y],36)+/*         p##@###YG=[#######y */(e=x=r=[]))for\
(r=!r,i=0;t[a/*         d#qg `*PWo##q#######D */]>i;i+=.05)wi\
th(Math)x-= /*        aem1k.com Q###KWR#### W[ */.05,0>cos(o=\
new Date/1e3/*      .Q#########Md#.###OP  A@ , */+x/PI)&&(e[~\
~(32*sin(o)*/* ,    (W#####Xx######.P^     T % */sin(.5+y/7))\
+60] =-~ r);/* #y    `^TqW####P###BP           */for(x=0;122>\
x;)p+="   *#"/* b.        OQ####x#K           */[e[x++]+e[x++\
]]||(S=("eval"/* l         `X#####D  ,       */+"(z=\'"+z.spl\
it(B = "\\\\")./*           G####B" #       */join(B+B).split\
(Q="\'").join(B+Q/*          VQBP`        */)+Q+")//m1k")[x/2\
+61*y-1]).fontcolor/*         TP         */(/\\w/.test(S)&&"#\
03B");document.body.innerHTML=p+=B+"\\n"}setTimeout(z)')//
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQSu/)

Comment: Cool animation...might end up using that somewhere actually!

Comment: It's minified code that contains comments (see those `/*` and `*/`?) - so it's nothing special at all.

Comment: @ThiefMaster try deleting any of those comments or even one character in it and run. then instead of deleting replace it and then try again.

Comment: Oh, nice. Didn't notice the fiddle.

Comment: This is called a Quine, and this is one of the more fantastic Quine's I've ever seen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: @TheMaster I have tried that , i can see changes in the behaviour , investigating it now , but , how could comments affect the code ?

Comment: This is brilliant! Kudos to whoever made it!

Comment: @Alexander checking for hash or length of the whole thing may be?

Comment: @Alexander: The entire string is assigned to the `z` variable, so the code inside can get the source from `z` and do a little parsing.

Comment: looks like europe and africa

Comment: @johnSmith: Did you click the jsFiddle link?

Comment: @DavidSouther not a quine. it doesn't reproduce itself, does it? :)

Comment: Quining... twerking for programmers? ;-P

Comment: `eval(z="console.log(z+'a');");` nice .. didnt know that i can manipulate the evaluated code from within itself .

Comment: Amazing... the spin... rotation... @Alexander can you please get the source and the Author of this shit?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan i think this is his page : http://aem1k.com/

Comment: Seems that there was a talk about construction of that thing on JSConf , http://2013.jsconf.eu/speakers/martin-kleppe-1024-seconds-of-js-wizardry.html

Comment: Does anyone else notice it kinda looks like a rotating globe?

Comment: Who wrote this code?!? Edit: Ah, thanks @Alexander!

Comment: @SchautDollar It is...

Comment: Seems like the author has now put up an [annotated version](https://github.com/aemkei/world/blob/master/annotated.js) on GitHub.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too far removed from the real world.

Comment: @DavidSouther What a one of a *Quine* ! ^^

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Foreword**: I beautified and annotated the code extensively at http://jsfiddle.net/WZXYr/2/

Consider the outermost layer:

```
eval(z = '...');
```

A code string is stored in the variable `z`. The assignment operator returns the value assigned, so the code string also is passed as an argument into `eval`.

The code string `z` runs inside of `eval`. The code is extremely obtuse, even when cleaned up, but it seems to:

1. Parse a string of base-36 numbers, delineated by the character `4`.
2. Populate a map of values, using the global variables `e`, `x`, and `y` to hold map state. Map state is, in part, a function of the current second on the wall clock (`new Date / 1e3`).
3. Using the map values, the code generates an output string, `p`

   - the code uses `p += "   *#"[index]` to decide whether to use a space, asterisk, or hash mark, where `index` is actually `e[x++] + e[x++]` (as said above, `e` and `x` are responsible for map state)
   - if the index is larger than the length of `"    *#"`, there is fallback code that populates the output `p` with characters from `z`. Inner characters are populated with animation characters, while outer characters are pulled from `z`.

At the end of the code, there is a call to `setTimeout(z)`, which asynchronously evaluates the code string `z`. This repeat invocation of `z` allows the code to loop.

**Simple example:**

Here's a super-simple version (http://jsfiddle.net/5QXn8/):

```
eval(z='p="<"+"pre>";for(i=0;i<172;++i)if(i > 62 && i < 67)p+="!---"[~~(new Date/1e2 + i)%4];else p += ("eval(z=\'" + z + "\')")[i];document.body.innerHTML = p;setTimeout(z)')
```

1. The `for` loop adds each character to the output string `p` (the string is 172 characters long):

   ```
   for(i=0;i<172;++i)
   ```
2. The inner conditional decides if we're on a character between position 62 to 67, which are the animated characters:

   ```
   if(i > 62 && i < 67)
   ```
3. If we are, then print out `!---`, shifted based on the tenth of the second wall-clock value. This provides the animation effect.

   ```
   p+="!---"[~~(new Date/1e2 + i)%4]
   ```

   (All the nastiness around `new Date` is really just there to transform a date value into a number between 0 and 3.)
4. Otherwise, if we're not on an animated character, then print the index-`i` character from the string defined by

   ```
   "eval(z='" + z + "')"
   ```

   That is, the code string `z` surrounded by `eval('` and `')`.
5. Finally, output the string and use `setTimeout` to queue up another execution of `z`:

   ```
   document.body.innerHTML = p;setTimeout(z)
   ```

Note that my final output isn't *quite* right -- I haven't accounted for the backslashes toward the end -- but it should still give you a pretty good idea of how the technique works generally.

Comment: Note this https://github.com/aemkei/world/blob/master/annotated.js - the author's own annotated version in GitHub.

Answer (score 36):

Here is the annotated source. Ps: I'm the author ;)

```
function z(){                     // will be replaced with eval

  p = "<" + "pre>";               // use <pre> tag for formatted output

  for (                           // loop though lines
    y in n = (                    // y - the line number
      "zw24"      +               // n - the encoded data
      "l6k4"      +               // every line holds encoded data
      "e3t4"      +
      "jnt4"      +               // string will be concated in build process
      "qj24"      +
      "xh2  4"    +               // data after spaces will be ignored but
      "2kty24"    +               // … is used to not break block comments
      "wrt4"      +               // … which will save some chars
      "13n24"     +
      "3n9h24"    +
      "3pdxt4"    +
      "1csb   4"  +
      "3iyb6k4"   +
      "3pk724"    +
      "3nmr24"
    ).split(4)                    // data will be split by (unused) 4

  ){
    for (                         // loop throug every char in line
      a in t = parseInt(          // numbers are encoded as string
        n[y],                     // … with a base of 36
        36
      ) + (                       // large number will be converted to string
        e =                       // e - holds the rendered globe
        x =                       // x - horizonal position
        r = []                    // r - bitmap flag if pixel is set
      )
    ){
      r = !r;                     // toggle binary flag

      for (                       // look though bitmap states
        i = 0;                 
        t[a] > i;                 // draw pixel t[a]-times
        i += .05
      )
        with (Math)               // refer to Math later
          x -= .05,
          0 > cos(                // prevent backface visibility
            o =
              new Date / 1e3 +    // get rotation based on current time
              x / PI
          ) && (
            e[                    // access matrix
              ~~(                 // convert float to integer
                sin(o) *          // rotate around y axis
                sin(.5 + y/7) *
                32                // scale up the globe
              ) + 60              // move to center
            ] = -~r               // store bitmap state in render matrix
          )
    }

    for (                         // loop through columns
      x = 0;
      122 > x;                    // break after char 122
    ) p += "   *#"[               // add space, asterisk or hash
        e[x++] +                  // … based pixel opacity
        e[x++]
      ] || (S = (                 // otherwise use the original code
        "eval(z='" +              // inception of missing "eval" statement
          z
            .split(B = "\\")      // escape \ with \\
            .join(B + B)

            .split(Q = "'")       // escape ' with \'
            .join(B + Q) +

          Q +                     // add missing ')

          ")////////"             // add extra chars to fill mapping
        )[
          x / 2 +                 // get character at current position
          61 * y-1
        ]

      ).fontcolor(                // colorize outpu
        /\w/.test(S) &&           // test for [0-9A-Z]
        "#03B"                    // render blue
                                  // otherwise pink (default)
      );

    document.body.innerHTML =     // render output
      p +=                        // append new line
      B +                         // add backspace
      "\n";                       // add new line
  }

  setTimeout(z)                   // render animation on next frame
}
z()
```

Comment: Note, it is also explained in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTxtiLp1C8Y

Answer (score 21):

Here is another manually deobfuscated version, moving all initialisation out of expression into own statements:

```
z='p="<"+"pre>"/* ,.oq#+     ,._, */;for(y in n="zw24l6k\
4e3t4jnt4qj24xh2 x/* =<,m#F^    A W###q. */42kty24wrt413n243n\
9h243pdxt41csb yz/* #K       q##H######Am */43iyb6k43pk7243nm\
r24".split(4)){/* dP      cpq#q##########b, */for(a in t=pars\
eInt(n[y],36)+/*         p##@###YG=[#######y */(e=x=r=[]))for\
(r=!r,i=0;t[a/*         d#qg `*PWo##q#######D */]>i;i+=.05)wi\
th(Math)x-= /*        aem1k.com Q###KWR#### W[ */.05,0>cos(o=\
new Date/1e3/*      .Q#########Md#.###OP  A@ , */+x/PI)&&(e[~\
~(32*sin(o)*/* ,    (W#####Xx######.P^     T % */sin(.5+y/7))\
+60] =-~ r);/* #y    `^TqW####P###BP           */for(x=0;122>\
x;)p+="   *#"/* b.        OQ####x#K           */[e[x++]+e[x++\
]]||(S=("eval"/* l         `X#####D  ,       */+"(z=\'"+z.spl\
it(B = "\\\\")./*           G####B" #       */join(B+B).split\
(Q="\'").join(B+Q/*          VQBP`        */)+Q+")//m1k")[x/2\
+61*y-1]).fontcolor/*         TP         */(/\\w/.test(S)&&"#\
03B");document.body.innerHTML=p+=B+"\\n"}setTimeout(z)';

p = "<" + "pre>";
n = ["zw2", "l6k", "e3t", "jnt", "qj2", "xh2 x/* =<,m#F^    A W###q. */", "2kty2", "wrt", "13n2", "3n9h2", "3pdxt", "1csb yz/* #K       q##H######Am */", "3iyb6k", "3pk72", "3nmr2", ""]
for (y in n) {
    e = [];
    x = 0;
    r = true;
    t = parseInt(n[y], 36) + "";
    for (a in t) {
        r = !r
        for (i = 0; i < t[a]; i += 0.05) {
             x -= 0.05;
             o = new Date / 1e3 + x / Math.PI
             if (Math.cos(o) < 0)
                 e[~~(32 * Math.sin(o) * Math.sin(0.5 + y / 7)) + 60] = -~r;
        }
    for (x = 0; x < 122;) {
        S = "eval" + "(z='" + z.split(B = "\\").join(B + B).split(Q = "'").join(B + Q) + Q + ")//m1k"
        p += "   *#"[e[x++] + e[x++]] || S[x/2+61*y-1]).fontcolor(/\w/.test(S[x/2+61*y-1]) && "#03B");
    }
    p += B + "\n";
    document.body.innerHTML = p;
}
setTimeout(z)
```

Here is what happens:

- `z` is a multiline string containing all of the code. It is [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)ed.
- At the end of the code, `z` is passed to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). It works like `requestAnimationFrame` and `eval` together, evaluating it in an interval at the highest possible rate.
- The code itself initialises `p`, the string buffer onto which the HTML will be appended, and `n`, an array of base-36-encoded numbers (joined into a string by `"4"`, the comments being irrelevant garbage that is not considered by [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).
- each number in `n` does encode one line (`n.length == 16`). It is now [enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).
- A bunch of variables is initialised, some disguised as the `e` array literal but they are then cast to numbers (`x`) or booleans (`r`) or strings (`t`) when used.
- Each digit in the number `t` is enumerated, inverting the boolean `r` each turn. For different angles `x`, and depending on the [current time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) `new Date / 1000` (so that it gives an animation), the array `e` is filled using some [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) - with `1` when `r` is false and `2`s when `r` is true at that time.
- Then a loop does iterate the 61 columns of the image, from `x=0` to 122 in double steps, appending single characters to `p`.
- `B` being the backslash, the string `S` is built from the code string `z` by escaping backslashes and apostrophes, to get an accurate representation of what it looked in the source.
- Every two consecutive numbers from `e` are added and used to access a character from `"   *#"`, to build up the animated image. If one of the indices is not defined, the `NaN` index resolves to an undefined character and instead the respective character from the `S` string is taken (check out the formula `x/2+61*y-1`). If that character should be a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), it is colored differently using the [`fontcolor` String method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor).
- After each line, the trailing backspace and a linebreak are added to `p`, and the HTML string gets assigned to the document body.

---

> How the same effect could be rewritten for a minimal example?

Here is an other example:

```js
setInterval(z='s=("setInterval(z=\'"+\
z.replace(/[\\\\\']/g,"\\\\$&")+"\')"\
).match(/.{1,37}/g).join("\\\\\\n");d\
ocument.body.innerHTML="<\\pre>"+s.sl\
ice(0, 175)+String( + new Date()).fon\
tcolor("red")+s.slice(188)')
```

It has all the releveant things you need for this kind of animation:

- `setInterval` and `Date` for the animation
- A reconstruction of its own code ([quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))-like), in here:

  ```
    s = ( "setInterval(z='" // the outer invokation
          + z.replace(/[\\\']/g,"\\$&") // the escaped version
        + "\')" ) // the end of the assignment
        .match(/.{1,37}/g).join("\\\n"); // chunked into lines
  ```
- The output via `document.body.innerHTML` and a `<pre>` element
- Replacing some parts of the code with the animated string

Comment: gotta admit, great answer!

Answer (score 5):

A string with the all the code is evaluated, and a timeout makes the loop;
The string is stored in a variable named `z` and in the middle of the code, between  comments `/*` and `*/`there is an "Earth ASCII Art".
The code parses the comments and changes the document content, keeping the js and updating the art. Bellow is just the code sliced:

```
  p="<pre>";
  for(y in n="zw24l6k4e3t4jnt4qj24xh2 x42kty24wrt413n243n9h243pdxt41csb yz43iyb6k43pk7243nmr24".split(4)){ 
    for(a in t = parseInt(n[y],36)+(e=x=r=[]))
      for(r=!r,i=0;t[a]>i;i+=.05)
        with(Math) x-= .05,0>cos(o=new Date/1e3+x/PI)&&(e[~~(32*sin(o)*sin(.5+y/7))+60] =-~ r);
          for(x=0;122>x;) p += "   *#"[e[x++]+e[x++\]] ||
              (S=("eval"+"(z=\'"+z.split(B = "\\\\").join(B+B).split(Q="\'").join(B+Q)+Q+")//m1k")[x/2+61*y-1]).fontcolor(/\\w/.test(S)&&"#\03B");
    p += B+"\\n"
    document.body.innerHTML= p
  }
```

Comment: Any way, incredible how around the Equator the graphic has more spin... amazing. +1 BTW